# How do I reference a particular UI Image or Sprite in my assets folder?

Tags: unity, c#

I have an `Item` class, and I want to associate an `Image` class with it. How do I get a reference to the intended `Image`, from my assets folder, in order to provide it as a reference to a constructor for `Item`?

---

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ItemData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private List<Item> items;

    void Start()
    {
        items = new List<Item>();

        Item sword = new Item(0, "Sword", /*What goes here?*/);
        items.Add(sword);

        Item hammer = new Item(0, "Hammer", /*What goes here?*/);
        items.Add(hammer);
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int itemID;
    public string itemName;
    public Image itemImage;

    public Item(int newItemID, string newItemName, Image newItemImage)
    {
        itemID = newItemID;
        itemName = newItemName;
        itemImage = newItemImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you might want to set up your Item as a ScriptableObject. Then each item can be an asset in your assets folder, and you can populate its name/image/etc. in the Inspector, rather than needing to define them in code at startup. Would something like that solve your problem, or would you prefer to dynamically load images by path & name, or store some type of image collection to pull them from?

Comment: As per my answer, I believe you may intend to use a `Sprite`. `Image` works, though it overcomplicates things. You would have a single `Image` in your scene - acting as the "container" - and swap out the `sprite` reference in order to change the displayed image. As such, I have left "sprite" in your question, even though you only note using `Image`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to provide a reference, via the Inspector. That said, you can use `Resources.Load()` to programmatically locate an asset in your Assets folder.

#### Direct Reference

You can provide a direct reference via the Inspector using a `public` reference or the `[SerializeField]` attribute. This allows you to drag and drop your reference in, in the actual Unity Editor. This may not be the best option, especially if you do not want to keep reference to your `Image` set in the `ItemData` class; however, given its simplicity, I feel it is important to make note of the option for completion sake.

```
public class ItemData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private List<Item> items;
    [SerializeField] private Image swordImage, hammerImage;

    void Start()
    {
        items = new List<Item>();

        Item sword = new Item(0, "Sword", swordImage);
        items.Add(sword);

        Item hammer = new Item(0, "Hammer", hammerImage);
        items.Add(hammer);
    }
}
```

#### Using `Resources.Load()`

The [`Resources`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.html) class provides functionality for locating assets from any available *Resources* directory, in your Project. We can use [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) to locate assets by name. Let's take a look at the official documentation:

> ### Resources.Load
>
> `public static Object Load(string path);`
>   `public static Object Load(string path, Type systemTypeInstance);`
>
> #### Parameters
>
> `path`       Pathname of the target folder. When using the empty string (i.e., ""),
>             the function will load the entire contents of the Resources folder.
>   `systemTypeInstance`	Type filter for objects returned.
>
> #### Description
>
> Loads an asset stored at `path` in a Resources folder.
>   Returns the asset at `path` if it can be found otherwise returns null. Only objects of `type` will be returned if this parameter is supplied. The `path` is relative to any Resources folder inside the Assets folder of your project, extensions must be omitted.
>   **Note:** All asset names and paths in Unity use forward slashes, paths using backslashes will **not** work.
>
> <sub>- [`Resources.Load()` @ official Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)</sub>

---

Now we know how it works, there are further matters to consider.

The first matter is our target type. You want to load an `Image`; but `Image` is a `MonoBehaviour`. You can not have a prefabed `Image` in your assets folder; but you *can* have a `GameObject` that *contains* an attached `Image`. Thus, we locate the `GameObject`, and use it to get the attached `Image`:

```
public class ItemData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private List<Item> items;

    /// <summary>The directory path inside the main "Resources" folder. We declare this as a
    /// const string, as it should not change. This allows us to write the directory path 
    /// once, and limit logical errors.</summary>
    private const string path = "ItemImages/"

    void Start()
    {
        items = new List<Item>();

        GameObject swordImage = Resources.Load(path + "SwordImage") as GameObject;

        Item sword = new Item(0, "Sword", swordImage.GetComponent<Image>());
        items.Add(sword);
    }
}
```

---

Perhaps you mean to find an actual image; that is, a `Sprite` to use when generating an `Image`. This might be a more efficient means to complete your desired functionality; but keep in mind that you will need to generate the `Image`, later, assuming you still intend to<sup>1</sup>. You would probably complete this functionality in a constructor for `Item`; specifically, `Item(int newItemID, string newItemName, Sprite newItemImage)`.

```
public class ItemData : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private List<Item> items;

    /// <summary>The directory path inside the main "Resources" folder. We declare this as a
    /// const string, as it should not change. This allows us to write the directory path 
    /// once, and limit logical errors.</summary>
    private const string path = "ItemImages/"

    void Start()
    {
        items = new List<Item>();

        Sprite swordImage = Resources.Load(path + "SwordImage") as Sprite;

        Item sword = new Item(0, "Sword", swordImage);
        items.Add(sword);
    }
}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> You may be using `Image` incorrectly. Think of `Image` as your UI container, and `Sprite` as your *actual* image. Typically, you would have a reference to the `Image` container in your scene view; and than replace its `sprite` reference with the desired `Sprite`, when you wish to change the display.</sub>

Comment: Going with the first direct reference suggestion though, I'm able to assign particular sprites to the objects and everything seems to be working fine. The one exception is that when I open the project I see the error 
Assets/Scripts/ItemData.cs(10,29): warning CS0649: Field `ItemData.anotherItemSprite' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value `null'. 
When I debug, I can see that it's not null, and in the inspector, I can see that it there is a sprite occupying the slot. Any reason I'm getting this message?

Comment: @embracethefuture, for future, if a post helped you, you should upvote it to let others know. For answers to your questions, you should accept the most helpful answers.

Comment: You would have to show us the code and inspector. Probably best to ask a new question, but Ill take a look.

Comment: Sounds good. I did that now. If you recommend me to start a new question, I can, but I figured since it's a quick question about something I run into when using one of your proposed solutions, I'd add it as a comment. I've figured out that this error will show for each sprite that isn't the first one. In the below example, this error will show for 'twoSprite' and 'oneSprite'. No matter how I switch the order, it will always show an error for all but the first one declared.

[SerializeField]
private Sprite threeSprite, twoSprite, oneSprite;